# How to set breakproint by GDB while running GUI of cpp applicaion

Tags: c++, linux, gdb

We have migrated one application from solaris to Linux. coding part was done in CPP.  If any core file created we are able to debug that by using GDB. Now we are getting some different error and no core file creating while running the application.

We want to know what happens in the application if we press some submit button. In this case how can we debug our cpp code and set breakpoints while running the application in GUI.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried starting the application with gdb. This [link](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~gilpin/tutorial/#3.2) provides method to run the application inside GDB. So with this your GUI application is launched in GDB and then with appropriate breakpoints, when "Submit" is clicked, the application must stop at relevant location.

In short, there must be not much change in running a GUI or non-GUI application with GDB in linux.

Comment: Hi Kumar.. thanks for quick update. The link you provided above is not wokring redirecting. Can you please past the url/